# Individual Character Boxing Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I am pulling a string from a database (SQL) and it is being put into a Crystal Report, C# is handling the connection strings.

I need get each character of the string (between 6 and 16) in it's own box. Similar to those of Direct Debit forms where they show Sort Codes.

Is this possible through Crystal Reports creator, using Visual Studio 2013?

If not through a function or option within Crystal Reports designer, then how would be best?

Comment: So you are trying to split a string into separate characters? Presumably the string doesn't have a delimiter? 

What RDMS are you using I might have something that does this.

Comment: I use SQL Management Studio - if I need to split the string, then yes, was cheekily hoping that Crystal would allow for individual character boxing, long shot that it would but we have to dream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately as far as I'm aware crystal won't deal with separate character boxing.

I have the following that I use for something similar, it's a little untidy but effective

```
declare @string varchar(16)
set @string = 'abcdefghijklmnop'

SELECT
LEFT(@string,1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,2),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,3),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,4),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,5),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,6),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,7),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,8),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,9),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,10),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,11),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,12),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,13),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,14),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,15),1)
```

Of course all you need to do is replace @string with your data and add in some alias's so you can make sense of it in crystal

SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/396

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `MID` (or `MID$`) function like this:

6th. character : `MID({yourField}, 6, 1)`
7th. character : `MID({yourField}, 7, 1)`
...
16th character : `MID({yourField}, 16, 1)`

Comment: Do you mean within the Crystal Reports Formula Fields?

Comment: @PurpleSmurph yes ;).